# Logging skipped items to a different file in the same spring batch job

Tags: spring, log4j, logging, spring-batch

I have a spring batch program where I am implementing skiplistener class as below:

```
public class MySkipListener implements SkipListener<SomeBean, SomeBean> {


public void onSkipInProcess(final SomeBean item, final Throwable t) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Skipped details during PROCESS is: " + t.getMessage());
    LogFactory.getLog("INFO" + MySkipListener.class.getName()).info(
        "Skipped details during PROCESS is: " + t.getMessage());    

}

public void onSkipInRead(final Throwable t) {

    System.out.println("Skipped details during READ is: " + t.getMessage());
    LogFactory.getLog("INFO" + MySkipListener.class.getName()).info(
        "Skipped details during READ is: " + t.getMessage());


}


public void onSkipInWrite(final SomeBean item, final Throwable t) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Skipped details during WRITE is: " + t.getMessage());
    LogFactory.getLog("INFO" + MySkipListener.class.getName()).info(
        "Skipped details during WRITE is: " + t.getMessage());
}

}
```

The log4j config is:

```
log4j.rootLogger=myLOG
log4j.appender.myLOG=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.myLOG.File=myLog.log
log4j.appender.myLOG.MaxFileSize=100KB
# Keep one backup file
log4j.appender.myLOG.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.myLOG.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.myLOG.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] [%c{1}] %-5p %x - %m%n
```

As clear all the logging statements goes into myLog.log including the statements from above skip listener class methods.

However, I do not want the skipped items logs going into the main log file. I want them to go to a separate file (e.g. skippedItems.log) so that I need not search for the skipped items line in the main log but get all the skipped items directly in a separate file.

What changes need I do for achieving this?

Below try is not working where myLOGTwo is a new appender in my config which is not added into rootLogger. So I want to add and remove it to rootLogger dynamically everytime I want to write through that appender.

```
Logger l = Logger.getRootLogger();
Appender a = l.getAppender("myLOGTwo");

l.addAppender(a);

LogFactory.getLog("INFO" + MySkipListener.class.getName()).info("Testing");

l.removeAppender(a);
```

Comment: why do you use add/removeAppender ? see e.g. http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=1311014 it works with getLogger("category")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the comment from Michael in the question above...